# javascript screen.width and screen.height not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-canvas, render

trying to make an element render the full size of the screen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
            canvas.style.background = "#0f0";
            canvas.style.width = screen.width + "px";
            canvas.style.height = screen.height + "px";

            console.log(
                "screen.width: " + screen.width +
                "\nscreen.height: " + screen.height +
                "\ncanvas.width: " + canvas.style.width +
                "\ncanvas.height: " + canvas.style.height
            );
        })()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but the canvas element renders with approximately twice the width and twice the height of the screen in chrome v22 but it seems to be fine in FF.
I get console output:

screen.width: 1366
screen.height: 768
canvas.width: 1366px
canvas.height: 768px

if I manually set the width and height of the canvas in chrome I have to use:

```
canvas.style.width = 780 + "px";
canvas.style.height = 435 + "px";
```

to get it to the size of the screen in chrome but then checking in FF this renders as expected to be just over half the screen in both dimensions.

update:

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body style="padding:0;margin:0;">
    <div>
        <canvas>
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
                canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];

            div.style.background = "#f00";
            div.style.width = screen.width + "px";
            div.style.height = screen.height + "px";

            canvas.style.background = "#0f0";
            canvas.style.width = "100%";
            canvas.style.height = "100%";

            console.log(
                "screen.width: " + screen.width +
                "\nscreen.height: " + screen.height +
                "\ncanvas.width: " + canvas.style.width +
                "\ncanvas.height: " + canvas.style.height
            );
        })()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it has the same effect, works in FF but not in chrome.

I did this before on my test site www.0xor1.com but I used jQuery `css({width:screen.width, height:screen.height})` to set it which is why it works but I don't understand why this way doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: Seems to working fine in chrome and FF, what browser are you testing it with?

Comment: As pointed out, setting your canvas dimensions with `style` isn't the right approach, but it should also be noted that a wider issue is likely to affect what you're trying to achieve depending on your implementation and target devices. Here is a great article detailing the quirks of calculating screen and viewport dimensions cross-platform. http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/

Comment: I couldn't see any problem with FF and chrome. Sometimes there could be a visual problem. You can measure the width and height by using a screen ruler like this. [Screen Ruler](http://wonderwebware.com/screen-ruler/)

Comment: Work OK in Firefox 15, Chrome22, and Opera11. Are you using MSIE?

Comment: I'm using chrome v22.0.1229.94 I've just tried it in FF and it works ok. my screen is 1366 x 768 and my logs say that the canvas is the same in "px" but it's definately rendering almost twice as big in each dimension. if I manually set the width and height of the canvas it's about 780px wide that makes it fill the screen :S which just confuses me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width and height of canvas element should be marked like:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200">
```

Css styles messes it up

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
canvas.width = screen.width + "px";
canvas.height = screen.height + "px";
```

without the `.style.`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your window is much smaller then your screen. You can't cover more then the window, so maybe screen isn't what you want.

if changed it so this, so it covers the whole body

```
        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        canvas.style.background = "#0f0";
        canvas.style.width = body.offsetWidth + "px";
        canvas.style.height = body.offsetHeight + "px";
```